# How do I write HAR data to a null Writer or OutputStream in Java?

Tags: java, string, java-io, outputstream, writer

I'm running a Browsermob Proxy while I surf via WebDriver to a video player app we're testing so I can read the headers and contents of our web service calls.  Specifically I want to make sure the right video filename is being passed when the driver clicks on a given link.

I want to convert the HAR object generated by BrowserMob into a string so I can search the string for `video_filename.flv` or whatever.  The proxy server has a `writeTo()` function that will dump its contents into either a `file`, an `OutputStream`, or a `Writer`.  Right now, stupidly, I'm dumping the results to a file and then ingesting the file right back into a string and parsing that:

```
    //...lots of WebDriver activity up here with BMP listening
    //...

    //get the HAR data
    Har har = server.getHar();

    //Output HAR to a file
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\output.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        har.writeTo(fos);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String harString = readFile("C:\\output.txt", StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    System.out.println(harString);
```

This works.

When I tried the same thing with a `Writer` or `OutputStream`, before I could even worry about converting either of those types into a string, I'd get complaints that these were null pointers.  Consider this:

```
    //get the HAR data
    Har har = server.getHar();

    //Output HAR to a Writer
    Writer harWriter = null;
    try {
        har.writeTo(harWriter);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Returns a null pointer exception.

And similarly for `OutputStream`.  Should be setting `harWriter` to some non-null value before I try to `writeTo()` it?  How do I accomplish that?

Behold, the stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.WriterBasedGenerator._flushBuffer(WriterBasedGenerator.java:1187)
at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.WriterBasedGenerator.close(WriterBasedGenerator.java:837)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:2004)
at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.writeValue(ObjectMapper.java:1581)
at net.lightbody.bmp.core.har.Har.writeTo(Har.java:30)
at com.videoplayer.CorrectVideosAreSentToThePlayer.teardown(CorrectVideosAreSentToThePlayer.java:152)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:77)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course you'll get a NullPointerException if you try to write to a null! Why would you think that would work?

You need to write to a `StringWriter` or something like that. That will give you a string.

Comment: But what did you think would happen? Write some data... nowhere... how would you have got the data out again?

Comment: I thought null would get replaced by the data is was writing to that object.  I didn't think that was so far-fetched.

Comment: So, you thought that it would trace the null back to the variable it came from and helpfully fill it in with a new Writer for you. Well, let me disabuse you of that notion. A null does not know where it came from in Java. Nor in any other language I know of. It's just nothingness. No data. That's all.

Comment: That isn't what I thought, not that it matters.  I obviously don't know enough about what a Writer is in the first place.  I thought a Writer was some other kind of data object that that I could convert this HAR object into, and then could be turned around and itself converted into a string.  You've been very helpful.  Thank you for disabusing me of my stupid notion.